# What is the VERB of this sentence

Tags: verbs, subjects

The following sentence is copied from theverge.com:

> "Tesla is reportedly working on a chip to handle all the tasks needed to power the fleet of fully self-driving cars that its CEO Elon Musk promised would be road-ready by 2019. "

I have no much idea about the subject and the verb in this sentence. It seems that there are two verbs dominate this sentence. Specially,  "**that its CEO Elon Musk promised would be road-ready by 2019**".

In this clause, what is subject of would?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will break it down by sucessively removing chunks of the sentence that are not the *main* sentence:

> "Tesla is reportedly working on a chip to handle all the tasks needed to power the fleet of fully self-driving cars that its CEO Elon Musk promised would be road-ready by 2019. "
>
> "Tesla is reportedly working on a chip to handle all the tasks needed to power the fleet of fully self-driving cars that its CEO Elon Musk promised `[things that he promised]` "
>
> "Tesla is reportedly working on a chip to handle all the tasks needed to power the fleet of fully self-driving cars that `[have a particular quality]` "
>
> "Tesla is reportedly working on a chip to handle all the tasks needed to power `[something]` "
>
> "Tesla is reportedly working on a chip to handle all the tasks `[of some type]`"
>
> "Tesla is reportedly working on a chip `[what kind of chip]`"
>
> "Tesla is `[adverb]` working `[on something]`"
>
> "Tesla ***is working***"

The main verb is ***is working.***

Answer (score 1):

To build on Adam's answer:  The main phrase is:

> Tesla is working on a chip.

The rest of the sentence is a long adjectival phrase that describes the chip.  It contains two subordinate adjectival phrases:

What is this chip?

> This chip will handle all of the tasks.

What tasks?

> The tasks to power the fleet of self-driving cars.

What cars?

> The cars Elon Musk promised would be road-read by 2019.